# IOS VideoToolbox insert pic_timing sei message?

Tags: ios, rtmp, video-toolbox

I have a trouble with AWS Medialive. I can't insert NALU: pic_timing SEI message (D.1.2 of ISO/IEC 14496-10-2005) into data and send to RTMP link.

I'm stumped. I couldn't find the answer AWS or Apple document.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Same issue .....